# Unable to Change Docker Registry URL

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry, docker-build

I am new to Docker, so I am trying to learn and build a docker image for my Spring Boot application.

My `Dockerfile` currently is very basic. I will add to it, once I figure out more about it.

```
# AS <NAME> to name this stage as maven
FROM eclipse-temurin:11-jdk-alpine as jdk
FROM maven:3.8.4 as maven
```

My Docker info is:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 20.10.17-ce
 Storage Driver: btrfs
  Build Version: Btrfs v4.15
  Library Version: 102
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux oci runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1
 runc version: v1.1.4-0-ga916309fff0f
 init version: 
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.14.21-150400.24.28-default
 Operating System: openSUSE Leap 15.4
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 1
 Total Memory: 9.714GiB
 Name: localhost.localdomain
 ID: CHSH:Q5ZQ:5MPU:X5MR:FG7M:IFV7:RG5Z:MKNO:KWG6:ZM4L:QX6E:QMNE
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Registry Mirrors:
  https://MY_DOCKER_URL/
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

My `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "log-level": "warn",
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "5"
  },
  "registry-mirrors": ["https://MY_DOCKER_URL/"]
}
```

I added the registry-mirror myself

My `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=http://docs.docker.com
After=network.target lvm2-monitor.service SuSEfirewall2.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/docker
Environment=“HTTP_PROXY=MY_COMPANYS_PROXY”
Environment=“HTTPS_PROXY=MY_COMPANYS_PROXY”
Environment=“NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1”

# While Docker has support for socket activation (-H fd://), this is not
# enabled by default because enabling socket activation means that on boot your
# containers won't start until someone tries to administer the Docker daemon.
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --add-runtime oci=/usr/sbin/docker-runc $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS $DOCKER_OPTS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID

# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity

# Uncomment TasksMax if your systemd version supports it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this property.
TasksMax=infinity

# Set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
# Only systemd 218 and above support this property.
Delegate=yes

# Kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup.
KillMode=process

# Restart the docker process if it exits prematurely.
Restart=on-failure
StartLimitBurst=3
StartLimitInterval=60s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I did login with the command:

sudo docker login -u MY_USERNAME -p MY_PASSWORD MY_CORPORATE_REGISTRY

But when I do a `docker pull`, it still tries to fetch from the docker hub registry:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  547.3kB
Step 1/3 : FROM eclipse-temurin:11-jdk-alpine as jdk
Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Any help on this would be really nice. I am struggling with this for two days!

Comment: So, this `eclipse-temurin:11-jdk-alpine` image is stored in your corporate registry called `MY_DOCKER_URL`, but you don't want your Dockerfile to explicitly say `FROM MY_DOCKER_URL/eclipse-temurin:11-jdk-alpine as jdk` (do I understand correctly?) which is what I would have tried with my limited knowledge as a workaround.  I admit I'm not sure how to do this with registry-mirrors or docker login either.  I'll be interested to see the answer too.

Comment: @Wyck I am assuming, and its a weak "assumption" coz of my lack of knowledge, that if i set the registry to my custom one, it will try to pull from that one without the `FROM`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
{
    "registry-mirrors": ["<your-registry-url>"]
}
```

to your `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and restart the docker daemon.